# Does Picture-in-Picture mode support Oreo?

Tags: android, youtube-api, picture-in-picture

I am working on Chat application in which you can share YouTube links. I want to play YouTube videos in my app like WhatsApp does. I do think they play video in PIP mode.

1. How do they play YouTube videos in app by using links?
2. Is it supported in Android Oreo?

I tried [this example](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-PictureInPicture), but it does not work with Android Oreo.

Answer (score 2):

1. Picture-in-picture allows to app run when the user switch to another app. The video popup on the WhastsApp is visible only in the app. It is not PIP. It's just a floating view which plays video in it.
2. Picture-in-Picture  requires Android 8.0 (API level 26) and above.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/picture-in-picture

Comment: Is their any documents or any example available for creating floating view to play YouTube video in app